typo3 9.5, news 8.6.0, display newslist of second language additionally at the page of default language
I have got a newsletter page with a special configuration, where both newslists of default and second language should display after another. For this, I tried with marks respectively subparts, in which the respective content is loaded.
    10 = TEMPLATE
    10 {
        template = FILE
        template.file = fileadmin/templates/newsletter/index.html
        workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_BODY
        subparts {
            CONTENT_DE < styles.content.get
            CONTENT_DE.select {
                languageField = 0
                where = colPos = 0 AND sys_language_uid = 0
        }
            CONTENT_OTHER < styles.content.get
            CONTENT_OTHER.select {
                languageField = 0
                where = colPos = 0 AND sys_language_uid = 9
            }
        }
    }

These subparts are places into the html-template of the newsletter page, which will be send with directmail to people partially not speaking the default language.
Extbase works with overlays, if another language is detected. This is actually not the case, it is the default language page. So I got two identically lists.
I think I have to write an XClass to overwrite the query behaviour of news for this special page. But I don't know, to which class I need to focus. I grepped news for 'getPropertyFromAspect', 'getRecordOverlay' etc. but didn't find the right point.
Or are there some other hints, that should be tried?
I tried multiple combinations of language settings of the page. I tried copying the localized data to another container and switched the localized plugin to fetch from it. Nothing helps. Perhaps I can fetch the foreign content from the localized page and put it into the default language with jQuery, after content has been rendered. But in front of this, an Xclass would be more fitting to a typo3 environment, more save for future upgrades and so on.
